# Create list using Custom list template JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I am trying to create a list using custom list template in SPO but I am getting error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$39_0' of undefined
>       at SP.ClientRequest.$3C_0 (sp.runtime.js:2)
>       at SP.ClientRequest.$3H_0 (sp.runtime.js:2)
>       at SP.ClientContext.executeClientRequestAsync (sp.runtime.js:2)
>       at SP.ClientContext.executeClientRequestAsync (sp.js:2)
>       at Array. (sp.runtime.js:2)
>       at ScriptResource.axd?d=Mc2groXhycX9-9HOevd9H4YLhMuHyaSg48Rru2qK9d69NSJpSVwhtPBb0sN4TWO7LXsL-cZypD02_ImoL6winpWs7RM5QvD0e7mhm8jDyFo75eDGwkHkoO8XV-E7MUPVXTIlZQ7SquetAU3C_OIUJ0XuVIYjvcS0lyW5WOx73PN_-uCftQApNVlltFgOURJ60&t=ffffffff85e60464:5
>       at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (ScriptResource.axd?d=Mc2groXhycX9-9HOevd9H4YLhMuHyaSg48Rru2qK9d69NSJpSVwhtPBb0sN4TWO7LXsL-cZypD02_ImoL6winpWs7RM5QvD0e7mhm8jDyFo75eDGwkHkoO8XV-E7MUPVXTIlZQ7SquetAU3C_OIUJ0XuVIYjvcS0lyW5WOx73PN_-uCftQApNVlltFgOURJ60&t=ffffffff85e60464:5)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=Mc2groXhycX9-9HOevd9H4YLhMuHyaSg48Rru2qK9d69NSJpSVwhtPBb0sN4TWO7LXsL-cZypD02_ImoL6winpWs7RM5QvD0e7mhm8jDyFo75eDGwkHkoO8XV-E7MUPVXTIlZQ7SquetAU3C_OIUJ0XuVIYjvcS0lyW5WOx73PN_-uCftQApNVlltFgOURJ60&t=ffffffff85e60464:5)

Below is my code snippet

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert("Success");
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function CreateListUsingTemplate() {
    hideProcessingDialog();
    debugger;
    var rootCTX = new SP.ClientContext('SharePoint URL');
    var web = rootCTX.get_web();

    var listTemplates = rootCTX.get_site().getCustomListTemplates(web);
    rootCTX.load(listTemplates);
    rootCTX.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var en = listTemplates.getEnumerator();
        while (en.moveNext()) {
            var item = en.get_current();
            if (item.get_name() === _templateName) {
                var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
                listCreationInfo.set_title('Actions');
                listCreationInfo.set_description('Actions');
                listCreationInfo.set_listTemplate(item);
                listCreationInfo.set_templateFeatureId("{00BFEA71-A83E-497E-9BA0-7A5C597D0107}");
                listCreationInfo.set_templateType(item.get_listTemplateTypeKind());
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_projectSiteURL);
                ctx.get_web().get_lists().add(listCreationInfo)
                    // ctx.load(myList);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
                );
                // ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                //     hideProcessingDialog();
                //     alert('List created');
                // }, function(sender, args) {
                //     hideProcessingDialog();
                //     alert('Failed to create list');
                //     alert(args.get_message());
                // }, function() {
                //     alert('');

                // });
            }

        }

    }, function(sender, args) {

        alert('failed to get list template');
        alert(args.get_message());

    });
```

[Refernce Use](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206932/sharepoint-online-create-list-from-custom-template-using-csom-jsom/206942)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think,set_listTemplate() of ListCreationInformation is not supported. because of this you are getting porperty undefined error. You will have to use CustomSchemaXml property of ListCreationInformation to create list(using your custom template).Create schema.xml for your custom list and pass this as a string to CustomSchemaXml property in javascript